# Removing <p> tags around <div> tags

Tags: tinymce, wp-autop

I’d like to stop WP from wrapping `<p>` tags around `<div>` tags in the TineMCE editor …

Here’s what I’ve got:

```
function filter_ptags_on_images($content) {
    return preg_replace('/<p>([^>]*)<\/p>/i', '$1', $content);
}

add_filter('the_content', 'filter_ptags_on_images');
```

That removes all `<p>` tags around text but nothing that is wrapped in `<p><div>text</div></p>`.

I’d also like to know a solution if I have nested `<div>` tags like `<p><div><div>text</div></div></p>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Greedy and Ungreedy modifier](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

`preg_replace( '/<p>(.+)<\/p>/Uuis', '$1', $content );`

Tested with this script:

```
<?php
$c = array();
$c[] = '<p>text</p>';
$c[] = '<p><div>text</div></p>';
$c[] = '<p><div><div>text</div></div></p>';

foreach ( $c as $content ) {
    $e = preg_replace( '/<p>(.+)<\/p>/Uuis', '$1', $content );
    var_dump( $e );
}
```

Also try `remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );`

Comment: Thanks for that! I’m afraid I forgot to mention, that I don’t want the `<p>` tags around text only shall not be removed—only the ones before `<div>` tags.

Comment: `preg_replace('/<p>((<div([^>]*)>)(.+)(<\/div>))<\/p>/iU', '$1', $content);` works for me. Is that correct? What does this `Uuis` at the end of the string mean?

Comment: The first line of my answer is a link to the PCRE pattern modifiers. The `u` modifier (lowercase u) treat the pattern as utf-8. This modifier should be used even when the pattern does not contain any utf-8 characters. If you always use this modifier, you don't get into trouble when the pattern contains utf-8 characters. The `s` modifier should be used because the content can contain linebreaks.